# Wrap function into loop

Tags: javascript, loops, timezone, momentjs

I have script that updates time for one tag if I use querySelector and updateTime(inputTime.value); but how do I create loop so it works for all elements using querySelectorAll.

I've tried for, foreach, but I just can't understand what's my mistake. I'm using moment js, timezone detection.

JS

```
if (!sessionStorage.getItem('timezone')) {
  var tz = jstz.determine() || 'UTC';
  sessionStorage.setItem('timezone', tz.name());
}
var currTz = sessionStorage.getItem('timezone');

var inputTime = document.querySelectorAll(".input-time");
var output = document.querySelectorAll(".local");

function updateTime(theTime) {

  var date = moment().format("YYYY-MM-DD");
  var stamp = date + "T" + theTime + "Z";

  var momentTime = moment(stamp);

  var tzTime = momentTime.tz(currTz);

  var formattedTime = tzTime.format('h:mm A');

  output.textContent = "Time in " + currTz + ": " + formattedTime;
}

var i;

for (i = 0; i < inputTime.length; ++i) {
  updateTime(inputTime[i].value);
}
```

HTML

```
<label for="input-time">Time in UTC: </label>
<input value="12:30" type="time" class="input-time">

<p class="local">x</p>

<label for="input-time">Time in UTC: </label>
<input value="12:30" type="time" class="input-time">

<p class="local">x</p>
```

Comment: why is there a `for` in the `label` tag shouldn't it be `class` instead?

Comment: Why are you using Moment-Timezone at all? If you just need to work with the user's local time, Moment can do that by itself.  Also, for new code projects the Moment team recommends using [Luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/) instead.

Comment: @midrizi label here is optional thing, can be deleted :)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint haven't heard of it, thank you Matt